# Stored procedure performance randomly plummets; trivial ALTER fixes it. Why?

Tags: .net, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I have a couple of stored procedures on SQL Server 2005 that I've noticed will suddenly take a significantly long time to complete when invoked from my ASP.NET MVC app running in an IIS6 web farm of four servers. Normal, expected execution time is less than a second; unexpected anomalous execution time is 25-45 seconds. The problem doesn't seem to ever correct itself.

However, if I ALTER the stored procedure (even if I don't change anything in the procedure, except to perhaps add a space to the script created by SSMS Modify command), the completion time reverts to expected completion time.

IIS and SQL Server are running on separate boxes, both running Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition. SQL Server is Standard Edition. All machines have dual Xeon E5450 3GHz CPUs and 4GB RAM. SQL Server is accessed using its TCP/IP protocol over gigabit ethernet (not sure what physical medium).

The problem is present from all web servers in the web farm. When I invoke the procedure from a query window in SSMS on my development machine, the procedure completes in normal time. This is strange because I was under the impression that SSMS used the same SqlClient driver as in .NET. When I point my development instance of the web app to the production database, I again get the anomalous long completion time. If my SqlCommand Timeout is too short, I get

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
> Timeout expired.  The timeout period
> elapsed prior to completion of the
> operation or the server is not
> responding.

**Question:** Why would performing ALTER on the stored procedure, without actually changing anything in it, restore the completion time to less than a second, as expected?

**Edit:** To clarify, when the procedure is running slow for the app, it simultaneously runs fine in SSMS with the same parameters. The only difference I can discern is login credentials (next time I notice the behavior, I'll be checking from SSMS with the same creds). The ultimate goal is to get the procs to sustainably run with expected speed without requiring occasional intervention.

**Resolution:** I wanted to to update this question in case others are experiencing this issue. Following the leads of the answers below, I was able to consistently reproduce this behavior. In order to test, I utilize `sp_recompile` and pass it one of the susceptible sprocs. I then initiate a website request from my browser that will invoke the sproc with atypical parameters. Lastly, I initiate a website request to a page that invokes the sproc with typical parameters, and observe that the request does not complete because of a SQL timeout on the sproc invocation.

To resolve this on SQL Server 2005, I've added `OPTIMIZE FOR` hints to my `SELECT`. The sprocs that were vulnerable all have the "all-in-one" pattern described in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bartd/sometimes-the-simplest-solution-isnt-the-best-solution-the-optional-parameter-problem). This pattern is certainly not ideal but was a necessary trade-off given the timeframe for the project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parameter sniffing and plan reuse. Every now and then you get a bad plan. Doing an ALTER bumps the metadata version on the procedure so the plans *must* be recompiled on next execution. The solution depends on a miriad of factors, you may have bad SQL, you may get an unlucky 'optimization', we can't possible know. Identify the statement in the procedure that is slow, when is slow. SQL Profiler is your friend, trace [SP:StmtCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189570.aspx) eevnt with a duration > 5000 for instance.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm no SQL expert; any explanation as to why it runs fine (with the same parameters) in SSMS?

Comment: Different connection settings, different user credentials, statistics got updated in the meantime, got lucky and found a good plan in cache. There could be miriad of reasons.

Comment: So am I correct in understanding that the same driver is used to communicate with the servers, and it's just a matter of how the configuration of the driver and invocation details? The baffling thing to me is that while the procedure is running slow for the site, it simultaneously runs fine in SSMS (only difference I can see is SQL credentials). That seems to rule out lucky plans or statistical updates.

Comment: Driver is not so important, but various connection settings (ANSI, ANSY NULLS etc) and the credentials are. Plans cannot be resused between different settings. SQL engine will routinely have tens of plans in memory for the very same procedure. Check sys.dm_exec_sessions for the SSMS spid and App spid. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx

Comment: Just to be technically accurate: driver is not important per se, but various drives have various defaults and there are differences between SqlClient, ODBC, OleDB, JDBC, PHP, FreeTDS and other drivers in terms of defaults.

Answer (score 5):

Execution plan was probably regenerated.

There are various ways you can force this to be regenerated, and also ways to avoid parameter sniffing, where an execution plan is determined based on the parameters, but which may not be suitable for all inputs.  If you were on 2008, I'd recommend using the `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` option.

Alternatively, mask all your input variables with local variables to avoid parameter sniffing, and consider calling WITH RECOMPILE or declaring the SPs that way.

Also, ensure that your statistics are up to date.  Out of date statistics might mean a plan is no longer good.

The comments in Remus' answer also indicate a number of things which can affect which plan the server picks.

Comment: Thanks for your help... Any idea why it would run fast in SSMS with the same parameters?

Comment: I will try WITH RECOMPILE, and as Remus also alluded to, input masking. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you say the query runs fine in SSMS, consider the following:

1. Query plans are cached based on the exact byte-for-byte structure of the query string, including white space
2. Plans for queries with parameters can be different than for queries with fixed values (corollary of #1)

You might try using SQL Profiler, and copy-and-paste the entire slow query from there into SSMS, to see if it's still slow.